# jquery selector extracts child and appends to another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Jquery children selector selects the img element and then extracts and removes the element and appends it to another div element.....why does this happens so? shouldnt it be a copy of the element that is being appended?

```js
var $anchors = $("#imageGallery a");
var $overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
$("body").append($overlay);
$anchors.click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 $overlay.show();
 var a = $(this).children();
 $overlay.append(a);
});

$overlay.click(function(){
 $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
body {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 background: #384047;
}
h1 {
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center
}

ul {
 list-style:none;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 display: block;
 max-width: 780px;
 text-align: center;
}
ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 8px;
 background:white;
 margin:10px;
}
ul li img {
 display: block;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

#overlay{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left:0;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <h1>Image Gallery</h1>
 <ul id="imageGallery">
  <li><a href="images/1.png"><img src="images/1.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href="images/2.png"><img src="images/2.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href="images/3.png"><img src="images/3.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href="images/4.png"><img src="images/4.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href="images/5.png"><img src="images/5.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href="images/6.png"><img src="images/6.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href="images/7.png"><img src="images/7.png"></a></li>
 </ul>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
 <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: This is how it works, the underlying native `appendChild` method does the same thing -> *"If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, `appendChild()` moves it from its current position to the new position "*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**clone()**](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) is the function use to copy any object and put it somewhere is DOM. This copying and pasting could be more cool with appendTo, prependTo, before and after function look how.

**[append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)** adds the object inside the selected elements.Lets go for basic one, add element as the last child of the selected elements, but do you really know that you can shift or move one object in DOM using this function.

**Changes Made**

```
var a = $(this).children().clone();
$overlay.empty().append(a);
```

**Working Example**

```js
var $anchors = $("#imageGallery a");
var $overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
$("body").append($overlay);
$anchors.click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 $overlay.show();
 var a = $(this).children().clone();
 $overlay.empty().append(a);
});

$overlay.click(function(){
 $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
body {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 background: #384047;
}
h1 {
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center
}

ul {
 list-style:none;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 display: block;
 max-width: 780px;
 text-align: center;
}
ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 8px;
 background:white;
 margin:10px;
}
ul li img {
 display: block;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

#overlay{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left:0;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <h1>Image Gallery</h1>
 <ul id="imageGallery">
  <li><a href="images/1.png"><img src="images/1.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href="images/2.png"><img src="images/2.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href="images/3.png"><img src="images/3.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href="images/4.png"><img src="images/4.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href="images/5.png"><img src="images/5.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href="images/6.png"><img src="images/6.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href="images/7.png"><img src="images/7.png"></a></li>
 </ul>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
 <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

No, append will just move the given elements(if you pass a jQuery object or dom element reference to it). You can clone the element and pass those to `append()`

```js
var $anchors = $("#imageGallery a");
var $overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
$("body").append($overlay);
$anchors.click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $overlay.show();
  var a = $(this).children().clone();
  $overlay.html(a);
});

$overlay.click(function() {
  $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #384047;
}
h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  max-width: 780px;
  text-align: center;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px;
  background: white;
  margin: 10px;
}
ul li img {
  display: block;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1>Image Gallery</h1>
  <ul id="imageGallery">
    <li>
      <a href="//placehold.it/64?text=1">
        <img src="//placehold.it/64?text=1">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="//placehold.it/64?text=2">
        <img src="//placehold.it/64?text=2">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="//placehold.it/64?text=3">
        <img src="//placehold.it/64?text=3">
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="//placehold.it/64?text=4">
        <img src="//placehold.it/64?text=4">
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var $anchors = $("#imageGallery a");
var $overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');

$("body").append($overlay);

$anchors.each(function(){
$(this).click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 $overlay.show();
 var a = $(this).children('img').clone();
 $('#overlay').html(a);
});
  });

$overlay.click(function(){
 $(this).hide();
});
```

```css
body {
 font-family: sans-serif;
 background: #384047;
}
h1 {
 color: #fff;
 text-align: center
}

ul {
 list-style:none;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 display: block;
 max-width: 780px;
 text-align: center;
}
ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 8px;
 background:white;
 margin:10px;
}
ul li img {
 display: block;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

#overlay{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left:0;
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <h1>Image Gallery</h1>
 <ul id="imageGallery">
  <li><a href="images/1.png"><img src="images/1.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href="images/2.png"><img src="images/2.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href="images/3.png"><img src="images/3.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href="images/4.png"><img src="images/4.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href="images/5.png"><img src="images/5.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href="images/6.png"><img src="images/6.png"></a></li>
      <li><a href="images/7.png"><img src="images/7.png"></a></li>
 </ul>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
 <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: yeah @RinoRaj , fixed. Thanks